# How to statically assess impact of trade volume on a rate?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

I have about 50,000 information about historical foreign exchange trades. For each trade I have the equivalent USD amount, the rate at which it was traded and the market rate. I am trying to understand what is the "optimal USD amount" at which we get the best rate.

So I calculated the percentage difference between the traded rate and market rate. Plotting everything on a graph, USD amount on x axis, and percentage difference on y doesn't really help because there are too many points.

So I thought about splitting the trades into groups and calculate the average:
from

0 to 100,000

100,000 to 200,000

200,000 to 300,000

etc

Then the problem I have then is that I have loads of trades in the first groups like 10,000, and just a few in the higher groups. So I am kind of feeling that this is statically wrong.

So what I also tried is to split the trades in group with the same number of trades in each one, so I have group :

0 to 20,000

20,000 to 50,000

...

1,000,000 to 2,000,000

The problem by bucketing trades like this, is that the result is greatly influenced by the choice of the buckets, that's why I don't think any of these method is 'mathematically' correct.

What would be a better method to understand the impact of the amount of currency you trade on the rate you get ?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just about how to make a graph that shows the relationship clearly, then one method I found useful is to have parallel boxplots with equally spaced groups but also have a histogram underneath, to show the size of each group.  I have a picture of this on slide 46 of [this presentation](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/NYASUG2011.pdf) (along with SAS code, if you are using SAS).